# How to do Image Processing in Android?

Tags: android, matlab, image-processing

I am new to Android and before I have a knowledge of Image Processing. I used MATLAB for IP but when now I have switched to Android I came to know that Android doesn't support MATLAB Functions or API. **So how can I carry out Image Processing in Android ?** Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Begin with [OPENCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html)

Comment: you can aslo use third party library for image processing:https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for ready-to-use implementations of common computer-vision algorithms, then [OpenCV4Android](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) or [FastCV](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/add-advanced-features/computer-vision-fastcv) libraries might be a good start.